# PHP: How to foreach in foreach with condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables, both connected via MySQL JOIN:

```
TableA:
hom_id  con_id
3       4
5       3

TableB:
hom_id  con_id  hp_id
3       4       1
3       4       2
```

My pseudo PHP Code:

```
foreach ($hom as $h) //from TableA
    echo $h->con_id
---myidea---    
        foreach ($pro as $p) //from TableB
            echo $p->hp_id
        endforeach
---END---
endforeach
```

The HTML result I got is:

```
Result HTML Table:
con_id      hp_id
3           1 2
4           1 2
```

What I want to have is:

```
result HTML:
con_id      hp_id
3           
4           1 2
```

I am pretty sure, that its just few line of php code which I have to change.
But I can't see the answer, please give me a hint how to change it.
Thanks

Comment: looks like you only want to echo the whole tableB at the last row of tableA . run inner foreach if last row of tableA is reached. there are methods to test : `row_count` etc.

Comment: too much pseudocode in your post. try to post something real not only pseudo. you can start from your real mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess a simple if would solve your problem, if I got ir right.

```
foreach ($hom as $h) {//from TableA
    echo $h->con_id
    foreach ($pro as $p) { //from TableB
        if ($p->con_id == $h->con_id) {
            echo $p->hp_id
        }
    }
}
```

Or, maybe you should just handle it in your SQL query, using a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: I knew it was just some simple php code in the right order ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use following sql statement:

```
select a.con_id,group_concat(b.hp_id SEPARATOR " ") as hp_id
from tableA a
left join tableB b on(a.hom_id=b.hom_id and a.con_id=b.con_id)
group by a.hom_id,a.con_id
```

It will give the result as per your requirement.

Comment: I love it when you can make mysql do all the work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try change your query?

```
SELECT A.con_id, B.hp_id
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON(A.con_id = B.con_id)
```

And do a simple foreach

```
foreach($result as $res)
{
    echo $res->con_id, $res->hp_id
}
```